# How to call a function/notification at specific offset/interval durations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, notifications, settimeout, setinterval

In my recent project, I came across a situation where I have to send a notifications to client based on specific schedule. For an example: schedule value is **8s,14s,20s** then first notification will be send after 8s, next is on 14s and last is on 20s.
How can we achieve this functionality?

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` to schedule the next notification to send.  If your time interval is constant, you can use `setInterval()`, but if it's not constant, then repeatedly use `setTimeout()` to schedule the next one.  When that one fires, use `setTimeout()` again to schedule the next one.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
function scheduleNotification(seconds){
  setTimeout(function(){
    // your logic here
    // you could also pass a callback to be executed here
  }, seconds * 1000);
}

function sendNotifications(){
  scheduleNotification(8);
  scheduleNotification(14);
  scheduleNotification(20);
}

sendNotifications();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const intervalDuration = [8, 14, 20]; // you can add or delete intervals

for (let i = 0, len = intervalDuration.length; i < len; i++) {
      setTimeout(\* function *\, intervalDuration[i] * 1000);
}
```

Here, you can add multiple interval based on your requirement. For your use case, setTimeout is the only option as you need to call notifications on different intervals.